# expo 5.5.1 Error: Unable to resolve module ./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4

Tags: expo, metro-bundler

**Environment**: Windows 10, VSCode, expo 5.5.1

**Steps to reproduce**:

1. Create a new expo app: `npx create-expo-app testApp`
2. go to testApp directory
3. Run `expo start`
4. Connect an Android device to pc
5. Press 'a' to launch app in Android

**Results:**

After bundling, the console shows
`Error: Unable to resolve module ./debugger-ui/debuggerWorker.aca173c4`

**Temporary solution**

`npm  install react-native-debugger`